# Google Webmaster Tools: failure to read robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt, google-search-console

I have a site where ALL connections will be redirected (from `http://`) to `https://`.

This is the way I did it in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This is working perfect, BUT …

Google Webmaster doesn't like it very much. It's fails to read my robots.txt. See

> [image: link screendump robots.txt Tester google webmaster tools]

So I added to .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/robots\.txt [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ http://example.com/robots.txt [NC,L]
```

But that doesn't work (enough), because the Webmaster Tool marked it also as a failure!

These links are without failure:

```
http://www.example.com/robots.txt
https://www.example.com/robots.txt
```

But these fail:

```
http://example.com/robots.txt
https://example.com/robots.txt
```

I'm trying now for 2 days! Some help is very welcome.

Comment: you might consider redirecting all of your `example.com` to `www.example.com` anyway because having two domains with the same content hurts your SEO

Comment: Thank you Jeff, but I would prefer it without the ugly 'www'. Is that possible? If "yes", How? ;-)

Comment: definitely, personally I do too, the important thing is to have just one domain and redirect all others to it.

Comment: Dear Jeff, now I have only one domain (without the www). But now I've another (little) problem. I'll make a new Question.